# Why is my animation not keeping location and rotation correctly?

Tags: animation, transforms

I am currently 3d modeling a twisty puzzle and trying to animate it. I have the puzzle done but when I try to animate it, it randomly twists and turns the individual objects in different directions before converging back to their original form at the end of the animation.

The screencast of me attempting to animate this is here: https://youtu.be/FiPcvhNzosk

File at the end of the screencast:

[image]

This is the original file. Just delete the 2 keyframes that are there:

[image]

I did make this with a tutorial. It is by rcpongo and I have very slightly edited his design. All credit goes to him for my design.

Comment: Can you upload your .blend to your post using http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Ok. I added it to the post.

Comment: I just saw another post and then checked the local x axis of all the pieces. They are different. The ones that are doing the odd wobble are the ones with a different local x. Can I just apply it or is there more I have to do?

Comment: Your post is becoming very confusing. I suggest that you delete the two blend files you added and upload the .blend that you are having trouble with. Additionally if you have additional information edit your post instead of using the "comments" section. Be patient and wait for people to offer advice. (No need to respond to this)

Comment: I found the answer. sorry about the confusing post.

Comment: Mind sharing the answer? On this site it's possible to answer your own question.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer after finding another similar post earlier. The post mentioned a local axis. I checked this on the pieces and found they did not have the same local x axis. I applied the rotation and it now works. How to fix this:

1. Select the pieces.
2. Press <kbd>R</kbd>,<kbd>X</kbd>,<kbd>X</kbd>> Move Mouse
3. If they rotate in different directions then the local x axes are different.
4. Select all the affected pieces and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>
5. Left click "rotation"
   That should fix other problems that are experienced.