# Why is my animation not correctly keeping location and rotation?

Tags: animation

I am sure that I set the keyframes location and rotation correctly, but it doesn't behave in that way. I can't find any solutions in Google nor Youtube.

https://pasteall.org/blend/caceeba41d4940ea8652bccd5ed23271

Comment: how to post my blender file?

Comment: you can share your file here: https://pasteall.org/blend/ ... but please show some screenshots and give more explanations

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/caceeba41d4940ea8652bccd5ed23271

Comment: I'm not very good at explaining in english so please see the link, I hope you can help me :D @moonboots

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please provide some context and explanation about your issue, don't just post, images, videos or links to external sites. See [What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “*How do I do this?*”](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/what-is-the-problem-with-posting-an-image-or-link-and-asking-how-do-i-do-this)

Comment: Also there is a question already with the exact same title as yours https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/96069/why-is-my-animation-not-keeping-location-and-rotation-correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The local orientation of the object (called *5 n 1 - ottoman.175*) is not aligned with the global orientation, which makes the rotation go crazy (at least in *Euler* mode as specified by Josh Sanfelici), so apply the rotation before creating animation (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > *Rotation*), or, maybe better for later use, apply the rotation, parent *5 n 1 - ottoman.175* to an empty, parent the empty to the main object, and rotate *5 n 1 - ottoman.175*. This way, however you rotate the main object, *5 n 1 - ottoman.175* will be able to rotate correctly.

[image]

Comment: OMG!!! after weeks of finding a right solution to this problem T-T I can now rest in peace <3

Comment: Thanks guys!! what a great community <3

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfect example of why we should use Quaternion rotations instead of Euler, when more than 2 axes of rotation are involved in a movement.

To simply solve, you can go to the first frame, switch to quaternions, insert a rot keyframe, turn back to euler, go to the second keyframe, switch to quaternion, insert a rot keyframe. Solved.

For this kind of objects it's better to build an armature or use some empties, make them parents of the objects, and use them to animate, so that those simple movements happen on a single rotation axis, and they get easily edited and automatically avoid theese problems.

Also, you should get the good habit of apply your rot and scale before animating (Ctrl A), and use real world dimensions (now it's 90 meters wide).